# How to use ctypes in IronPython in SharpDevelop?

Tags: ironpython, ctypes, sharpdevelop

I am using SharpDevelop 4.4 and IronPython 2.7.5 in Windows 8 32 pc. I can't use ctypes in Sharpdevelop. But i can in IronPython console and even in visual studio(2013). When i type "import ctypes" SharpDevelop shows me an intellisence item "_ctypes" and "_ctypes_test". How to fix this. 
This is worked code in visual studio

```
sd = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
sd.Beep(500,1000)
```

And this is the code worked in IronPython console

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.Beep(500,1000)
```

Both of these methods are not working in SharpDevelop.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by not working? That doesn't really tell me a lot. I understand it isn't giving you intellisense, but does the code run? If not, what is the traceback?

Comment: SharpDevelop gives no error traceback but the console window has some text but it is vanishing very quick.

Comment: you can keep the console window open by putting `raw_input('Press enter to continue')` at the end of the script and put the rest in a try/catch block if you want.